# In PyQt5 How to call function or method after load aplication?

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import time

def show_message(self):
    time.sleep(5)
    self.label.setText("It's me")
    

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Hello', self)
        
        #How to call this func after load application
        show_message(self)
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    
    application = Main()
    application.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How to call `show_message(self)` after load `application`
Does pyqt5 have a function or method like `self.afterLoad(application, show_message)`
It seems to me something like this available on tkinter

Comment: Firstly, get rid of the `time.sleep` as it will block all event-processing and freeze the GUI. Secondly, make `show_message` a method of `Main` and use `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.show_message)` to run the method after 5000ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want to start the application and then after 5 seconds the text in the label will get changed to the new text.

What you have right now is almost working, however the problem is that when you call time.sleep(5) then the whole execution of the program will get paused and nothing gets shown for that amount of time. If you still wanna be able to interact with the program during those 5 seconds then you will need to use a timer that is running in the background instead.

PyQt already has something like that in PyQt5.QtCore.QTimer. If you use that then your code could look something like this

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer                # Importing QTimer
import time

def show_message(self):
    self.label.setText("It's me")

    # Stopping the timer. Otherwise it will run over and over again.
    self.timer.stop()                          
    

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Hello', self)
        
        # Create a new QTimer
        self.timer = QTimer(self)              

        # Tell the timer that it should call show_message(self) when the time runs out
        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda: show_message(self))      

        # Start the timer which then starts running in the background for 5 seconds
        self.timer.start(5000)                 
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    
    application = Main()
    application.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

One last thing that I would recommend doing is putting your functions that belong to a class inside of it. So here it would probably be better to put show_message inside of the main class because right now you can call the function from every part of the code and that can lead to errors.

Comment: There's no point in stopping a timer that is known to be run just once. Just use the `singleShot()` static: `QTimer.singleShot(5000, lambda: self.label.setText("It's me"))`.